# how to use boost::algorithm::join on tuples?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, c++11

`boost::algorithm::join` provides a convenient join on `std::vector<std::string>`.

How would you expand this functionality to use `std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,bool>>` to surround the results with single-quotes (for strings) if true, before doing the join.

This is not hard to do with loops, but I am looking for a solution that **makes the most use of standard algorithms and C++11 features** (eg lambdas).

Continue to use boost's join, if feasible:  **elegance/readability/conciseness** are more important.

**CODE**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp> 

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::vector<std::string> fields = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
  auto simple_case = boost::algorithm::join( fields, "|" );

  // TODO join surrounded by single-quotes if std::get<1>()==true
  std::vector<std::tuple< std::string, bool >> tuples =
   { { "42", false }, { "foo", true }, { "3.14159", false } };

  // 42|'foo'|3.14159 is our goal
}
```

**EDIT**

OK, I took kassak's suggestion below and took a look at `boost::transform_iterator()` - I got put off by the verbosity of the example in boost's own documentation, so I tried `std::transform()` - it's not as short as I wanted, but it seems to work.

**ANSWER**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp> 

static std::string
quoted_join( 
    const std::vector<std::tuple< std::string, bool >>& tuples, 
    const std::string& join
)
{
    std::vector< std::string >  quoted;
    quoted.resize( tuples.size() );
    std::transform( tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), quoted.begin(),
        []( std::tuple< std::string, bool > const& t ) 
        {
            return std::get<1>( t ) ? 
                "'" + std::get<0>(t) + "'" :
                std::get<0>(t);
        }
    );
  return boost::algorithm::join( quoted, join );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::vector<std::tuple< std::string, bool >> tuples =
  { 
    std::make_tuple( "42", false ), 
    std::make_tuple( "foo", true ), 
    std::make_tuple( "3.14159", false ) 
  };

  std::cerr << quoted_join( tuples, "|" ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The downside of your version is that it is two steps: a complete copy of the vector file is made.

Comment: @Yakk if you can put up a better version (in code) as an answer, I'll +1 your post (it'd be nice to do it in one shot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use join, you could wrap collection in `boost::transform_iterator` and add quotes if needed

Comment: You could pass transformed iterators as `std::pair` to join algorithm, like in @Yakk 's answer.
That would be better, you won't have memory overhead, your `quoted` sequence would be evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 3):

First write `make_transform_range( old_range, functor )`.  For a first version assume `old_range` is a `std::pair` of iterators, but ideally it should be anything that admits `begin(c)`.

Then the answer becomes really clean and efficient.  Take the range you are working on, transform it without actually calling the functions, then call join on it.

In am on my phone, so typing up the rather hairy `make_transform_range` is beyond me.  And it is pretty hairy.

Here is a less abstracted attempt.

```
auto functor = []( my_pair const&p )->std::string {
  if (p.second) return quote( p.first );
  return p.first;
};
auto tbegin = boost::make_transform_iterator( b, functor );
auto tend = boost::make_transform_iterator( e, functor );
join(…);
```

...which is less nasty than I feared, if it works.  I still think `make_transform_range` is worth it, but maybe not for a one off.

Another approach would be the boost range library, with all that funky syntax.  It has ranged based transform already.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to use [Boost.Range](http://boost.org/libs/range)'s `transformed` adaptor:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp> 
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple< std::string, bool >> tuples =
    { 
        std::make_tuple( "42", false ), 
        std::make_tuple( "foo", true ), 
        std::make_tuple( "3.14159", false ) 
    };

  std::cout
      << boost::algorithm::join( 
                tuples | boost::adaptors::transformed(
                    [](std::tuple< std::string, bool > const &tup){
                        return std::get<1>(tup) ? 
                            "'" + std::get<0>(tup) + "'" :
                                  std::get<0>(tup);
                    }
                ), "|" )
      << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not a generic one for that why not just loop through the vector and append the strings ?

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, bool>> coll;
coll.push_back(make_tuple("foo", false));
coll.push_back(make_tuple("bar", true));
coll.push_back(make_tuple("foo", false));
std::string result;
result.reserve(coll.size());

for(auto& val : coll)
{
  result += std::get<1>(val) ? ("'" + std::get<0>(val) + "'|") 
                             : std::get<0>(val) + "|";
}

boost::trim_if(result, boost::is_any_of("|"));
std::cout << result << "\n";
```